# What does the Tab Control's ContainsKey() method compare against?

Tags: winforms, controls

I want to create a Tab Control that only opens content once.  Each item that is opened needs to check the container to make sure it isn't already being displayed.  I believe the method I want to use is the [bool TabControl.TabPages.ContainsKey(string key)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.tabpagecollection.containskey.aspx) method, however it always returns a value of *false*.

I've created a work-around where I store the object in a separate list that I keep in sync with the tab control, but it feels very wrong.  I have a list in the TabPages property of the control, so I should be able to query against it.

Am I missing a property?  Is my expectation of this method and what it's performing correct?  How do I get it to correctly identify my opened tabs?

Here is some sample code that is similar to what I'm doing:

```
private void _fillTabControl()
{
    List<string> keys = new List<string>() { "one", "two" };
    foreach (string key in keys)
        _addTab(key);

    bool alreadyOpened = tabControl.TabPages.ContainsKey(keys[0]);
}
private void _addTab(string key)
{
    TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
    textBox.Text = key;

    TabPage tab = new TabPage();
    tab.Text = key;

    tab.Controls.Add(textBox);
    tabControl.TabPages.Add(tab);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The doc says it all:

"The **Name** property corresponds to the key for a TabPage in the TabControl.TabPageCollection."

You're using the Text property, you should set

```
tab.Name = "MyName";
```

and then

```
tabControl.TabPages.ContainsKey("MyName");
```

will return true;

Comment: Man...momentary blindness.  Thanks.